# How to update an ASP.NET label with SqlDataSource return value

Tags: asp.net

On an ASP.NET page, I have a SqlDataSource configured with the following SELECT command:

`SELECT AVG(Rating) FROM [Ratings] WHERE ([AlbumID] = @AlbumID)`

How would I place that average value into a label?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use FormView control to put the Label in.

Something like this:

```
<asp:formview id="formview1" runat="server" datasourceid="your-datasource-id">
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:label id="label1" runat="server" text='<%# Eval("column-name") %>' />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:formview>
```

Replace `your-datasource-id` and `column-name` in the above code.

PS: you might need to alter the query to have a column-name for that one value:

```
SELECT AVG(Rating) AS "average" FROM [Ratings] WHERE ([AlbumID] = @AlbumID)
```